# How can I use a different email send method for the Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail method in Meteor?

Tags: email, meteor, mandrill

I use Mandrill to send emails from within Meteor. I don't have the default email method configured. I use this smart package https://github.com/Wylio/meteor-mandrill

Is there a way to change the Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail method to use a smart package to send the email?

Right now I get the error below when I try to use that method.

Here is my error trace

```
message: Invalid login - 435 4.7.8 Error: authentication failed: 
 421 4.7.0 ip-10-102-139-231 Error: too many errors stack:
AuthError: Invalid login - 435 4.7.8 Error: authentication failed: 
    at Object.Future.wait (/Users/Bechard/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.36.15lvyk8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
    at smtpSend (packages/email/email.js:91)
    at Object.Email.send (packages/email/email.js:168)
    at Object.Email.send (packages/meteorhacks:kadira/lib/hijack/email.js:9)
    at Object.Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:460)
    at Object.Utils.create_user (app/server/lib/globals.js:83:22)
    at Meteor.methods.singleDonation (app/server/methods/donate.js:73:36)
    at methodMap.(anonymous function) (packages/meteorhacks:kadira/lib/hijack/wrap_session.js:182)
    at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1599)
    at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:648
    - - - - -
421 4.7.0 ip-10-102-139-231 Error: too many errors
    at SMTPClient._actionAUTHComplete (/Users/Bechard/.meteor/packages/email/.1.0.4.ioat51++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/simplesmtp/lib/client.js:826:23)
    at SMTPClient._onData (/Users/Bechard/.meteor/packages/email/.1.0.4.ioat51++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/simplesmtp/lib/client.js:329:29)
    at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at CleartextStream.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:748:14)
    at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:410:10)
    at _stream_readable.js:403:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Comment: I've updated [wylio:mandrill's README](https://github.com/Wylio/meteor-mandrill) to explain how to [use Meteor's Account.emailTemplates](https://github.com/Wylio/meteor-mandrill#using-meteors-accountsemailtemplates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't declare the Mandrill key in my startup function.

I originally had this

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  return Meteor.Mandrill.config({
    username: Meteor.settings.mandrillUsername
  });
});
```

I changed it to this and the email sent fine.

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  return Meteor.Mandrill.config({
    username: Meteor.settings.mandrillUsername,
    "key": Meteor.settings.mandrillKey
  });
});
```